# Adding javascript ID as Href

Tags: javascript, html

***Goal:*** Everytime a user refreshes the page, there will be a new *random* "square"  with the text (label) and image (icon) on it, when a users clicks the "square" it will redirect to a new link (href).

***My Plan:***
The objects from the array (myArray) will be randomly picked every time the page gets refreshed. The value of the properties (label, icon and href) from the object will be called and will be used to create the "square".

***This is what I have go so far:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>   
  var myArray = [{
    label: "Appels",
    icon: "./Appels.png",
    href: "./Appels.html"
  }, {
    label: "Pears",
    icon: "./Pears.png",
    href: "./Pears.html"
  }, {
    label: "Banana",
    icon: "./Banana.png",
    href: "./Banana.html"
  }, {
    label: "Mango",
    icon: "./Mango.png",
    href: "./Mango.html"
  }];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem3 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem4 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("randomItem1label").innerHTML = randomItem1.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem1icon").innerHTML = randomItem1.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem1href").innerHTML = randomItem1.href; 
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem2label").innerHTML = randomItem2.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem2icon").innerHTML = randomItem2.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem2href").innerHTML = randomItem2.href;
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem3label").innerHTML = randomItem3.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem3icon").innerHTML = randomItem3.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem3href").innerHTML = randomItem3.href;
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem4label").innerHTML = randomItem4.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem4icon").innerHTML = randomItem4.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem4href").innerHTML = randomItem4.href;      

  });
</script>
<p>Random 1</p>
    
  <!-- <div id = "randomItem1label"> </div> -->
  <div id = "randomItem1icon"> </div>
  <div id = "randomItem1href"> </div>  

<p>Random 2</p>
    <div id = "randomItem2label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem2icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem2href"> </div>
    
<p>Random 3</p>
    <div id = "randomItem3label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem3icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem3href"> </div>
    
<p>Random 4</p>
    <div id = "randomItem4label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem4icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem4href"> </div>
         
<hr>
    Making of the "Square" without CSS (So not really a square)
<hr>
    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="block">
                    <a href="/placeholderlink" id="testlink"> <!-- href -->
                        <div class="block_icon">
                            <img src=""> <!-- icon -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_info">
                               <div id = "randomItem1label"> </div>  <!-- Label -->
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>   
  
    <script>
    var link =  document.getElementById("testlink");
    link.setAttribute("href",    "ID FROM  id = randomItem1href HERE  " );    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the Label id is inserted into the "square"

***Problem:***
The properties, icon and href are not inserted into the "square".
I have tried to use `link.setAttribute` but I'm having a problem with adding the id.

```
<div id = "randomItem1href"> </div>    
<a href="/placeholderlink" id="testlink"> <!-- href -->

 <script>
  var link =  document.getElementById("testlink");
  link.setAttribute("href", ***id = "randomItem1href"*** );    
 </script>
```

***id = "randomItem1href"*** Doesnt work how can I put my value of the id there.

I hope my problem is clear.

SOLVED

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. note: it is not a 'JS id'. id is an attribute on a HTML element.

Comment: Provided you have grabbed the element using `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`, you can now do `element.getAttribute("id")` and `element.setAttribute("href", some_value)`

Comment: What do you want to achieve here, if its just for navigation try `href="#<id>"`

Comment: I wonder where the "ids" come from. What happens when you have the same "id" multiple times? You won't be able to access them properly and your html becomes invalid after all. You should avoid abusing html attributes for something else.

Comment: _"but I hope you can get the an idea what i'm trying to achieve"_ - no, not at all; actually, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286047).

Comment: Others have already addressed other aspects of this, so I’ll ask: are you sure you’re improving the user’s experience by adding this layer of indirection? You’re making basic navigation and displaying images dependent on JavaScript, which adds more failure conditions on top of the normal ones, such as errors in the source or even slow or incomplete downloads, not to mention JS being disabled by the user. Could this perhaps be solved in a template on the server side instead?

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for the answer, I have tried too implement  lement.setAttribute("href", some_value). I cant seem to find how to replace " some_value" with the value of the id. I have edited my post

Comment: @CBroe I have edited my post, I hope you could understand it now

Comment: @Reginald1234 The main problem here is that you need to grab the div to read its id, but there's nothing setting that div apart from all the others except for the `id`. It's a catch 22 basically. Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286047) and make sure you're asking about X, not Y.

Comment: No, I still don't understand, because you have still not made a proper attempt at explaining what you want to _achieve_ here in the first place. _Why_ do you need to switch out the href of this link, and _why_ is the source of the new one this particular div? Or, to put it another way, what is the _context_ of this, what actual problem are you trying to solve resp. what functionality are you trying to implement this way?

Comment: @CBroe I have tried to explain my problem in detail, I hope the problem is clear.

Comment: Goal: Understood (kinda, I think.) Plan: Way to complicated ... Why that detour via those divs elements and their weird ids? Scratch that, and set the label, icon and href retrieved from one randomly selected array element directly in the appropriate places of your link template element when the document gets loaded.

Comment: @CBroe Okay, Could you give me a code example?

Comment: @vizsatiz I have edited my post

Comment: @Reginald1234 Updated my answer with a sample of your code and what I changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the *id* and its *value* should be used as a url parameter, you could do something like this, and append it to the anchors `href`

Stack snippet

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#randomItem1href');
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');

anchor.href += "?id=" + div.id;

console.log(anchor.href)
```

```html
<div id = "randomItem1href"> </div>  

<a href="some_url">some url</a>
```

---

Updated after question edit

Here is an update of your code snippet, where I changed it like this, and if you refresh it, it will randomly sort the items and with that its `href`

```
var link =  document.getElementById("testlink");
link.href = randomItem4.href;
```

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>   
  var myArray = [{
    label: "Appels",
    icon: "./Appels.png",
    href: "./Appels.html"
  }, {
    label: "Pears",
    icon: "./Pears.png",
    href: "./Pears.html"
  }, {
    label: "Banana",
    icon: "./Banana.png",
    href: "./Banana.html"
  }, {
    label: "Mango",
    icon: "./Mango.png",
    href: "./Mango.html"
  }];

  var randomItem1 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem2 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem3 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomItem4 = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("randomItem1label").innerHTML = randomItem1.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem1icon").innerHTML = randomItem1.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem1href").innerHTML = randomItem1.href; 
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem2label").innerHTML = randomItem2.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem2icon").innerHTML = randomItem2.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem2href").innerHTML = randomItem2.href;
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem3label").innerHTML = randomItem3.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem3icon").innerHTML = randomItem3.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem3href").innerHTML = randomItem3.href;
      
    document.getElementById("randomItem4label").innerHTML = randomItem4.label;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem4icon").innerHTML = randomItem4.icon;  
    document.getElementById("randomItem4href").innerHTML = randomItem4.href;      

  });
</script>
<p>Random 1</p>
    
  <!-- <div id = "randomItem1label"> </div> -->
  <div id = "randomItem1icon"> </div>
  <div id = "randomItem1href"> </div>  

<p>Random 2</p>
    <div id = "randomItem2label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem2icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem2href"> </div>
    
<p>Random 3</p>
    <div id = "randomItem3label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem3icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem3href"> </div>
    
<p>Random 4</p>
    <div id = "randomItem4label"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem4icon"> </div>
    <div id = "randomItem4href"> </div>
         
<hr>
    Making of the "Square" without CSS (So not really a square)
<hr>
    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="block">
                    <a href="/placeholderlink" id="testlink"> <!-- href -->
                        <div class="block_icon">
                            <img src=""> <!-- icon -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_info">
                               <div id = "randomItem1label"> </div>  <!-- Label -->
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>   
  
    <script>
    var link =  document.getElementById("testlink");
    link.href = randomItem1.href;    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the input. The href part works! When I tried to do the same with the img. The picture didn't how up in the browser. Even when the path is correct, I also looked up randomItem1.icon in the console and it also gives the same path to the picture. I also edited my post again.

Comment: @Reginald1234 For this I really need an upvote too ;) ... you should use `img.src`, not `img.icon` like this `img.src = randomItem1.icon;`

Answer (score -2):

you can also choose ID using this code

href="javascript:{document.getElementById("yourid"),submit()}"

Comment: Try it out and tell me if this really works. You need a `window.open` in your script. Also, for image src it won't work at all